# How to create an HTML link in Dart?

Tags: html, dart

I would like to create an HTML link with Dart.

Where in HTML I would write:

```html
You can click <a href="url_1">here</a> and <a href="url_2">there</a>.
```

I do not know how to do it in Dart. I tried something like:

```dart
LinkElement link1;
link1.href = "url1";
```

I do not know how to insert the `link1` object within a static sentence like the HTML example above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to do it; here are two:

```dart
import 'dart:html';

void main() {
  // Method one: build everything from scratch
  var p = new ParagraphElement();
  var link1 = new AnchorElement()
    ..href = 'url_1'
    ..text = 'here';
  var link2 = new AnchorElement()
    ..href = 'url_2'
    ..text = 'there';

  p ..appendText('You can click ')
    ..append(link1)
    ..appendText(' and ')
    ..append(link2)
    ..appendText('.');

  document.body.children.add(p);

  // Method two: just set `innerHtml` with an HTML fragment
  var p2 = new ParagraphElement()
    ..innerHtml = 'You can click <a href="url_1">here</a> '
                  'and <a href="url_2">there</a>.';

  document.body.children.add(p2);
}
```

You can do something in between those two extremes, or you could write it in an HTML file as you're used to, giving the pieces you need appropriate `id`s or `class`es so you can access them from Dart.  It's hard to know from your question exactly what your needs are, but these options should cover whatever you find appropriate for your case.